# How to run specific method after specific time?

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee

Each user may have many vehicles, if after two minutes no  vehicle was added to a user, application must run a specific method, how can I implement it ?

I have two classes as following :

```
Class User

   private int ID; 
   private int Username;
   private list vehicle = new Vehicle();

   @OneToMany (cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   public list getVehicle(){
      return vehicle;
   }
   ....

Class Vehicle

   private int ID;
   private int VehicleName
   ....
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you add the record you need to issue a thread that will sleep for 2 minutes and after two minutes will check the table.

Answer (score 1):

Better option use trigger in your database,

**Steps:**

1) activate after insertion in User table

2) use **'WAITFOR'** command if you are using sqlserver or find similar according to database for 2 minutes

3) check if that user related entry not inserted into UserVehicle Table than remove user from User Table.